# Encryption with Javascript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE) with JWT in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, jose

I am trying to integrate [Javascript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE) jose](http://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#id8) with My iOS App.

Referred [This Sample code : hongkongkiwi/ObjectiveC-JOSE](https://github.com/hongkongkiwi/ObjectiveC-JOSE)..using to this trying to send my input parameters as encrypted format to server .

If any has integrated the JOSE please provide me the process.

Currently I have implemented :

```
   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =[[self dataSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        completionHandler(nil,error);
        return ;
    }

    id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"response object :%@",responseObject);
}
```

Actually I found A snippet for decoding using JOSE :

http://popdevelop.com/2013/12/decode-json-web-token-jwt-in-ios-objective-c/
But not found any library for encoding..SO I doubt is whether encoding with JOSE is possible with iOS or not ?

Comment: So, did you hit any roadblocks? What does not work?

Comment: @Thilo Please find my update..I have updated in question now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with **JSON WEB TOKEN** **cocoa pods** sample.

Install cocoa pod with:

> **pod "JWT"**

To encode & decode JWTs, use fluent style with the JWTBuilder interface

- (JWTBuilder *)encodePayload:(NSDictionary *)payload;
- (JWTBuilder *)encodeClaimsSet:(JWTClaimsSet *)claimsSet;
- (JWTBuilder *)decodeMessage:(NSString *)message;

**You can encode arbitrary payloads like so:**

```
 NSDictionary *payload = @{@"foo" : @"bar"};
 NSString *secret = @"your secret key";
 id<JWTAlgorithm> algorithm = [JWTAlgorithmFactory  algorithmByName:@"HS256"];

 [JWTBuilder encodePayload:payload].secret(@"secret").algorithm(algorithm).encode;
```

JWT token will be like this Sample:

> "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiI1NmY2YWUxYjYwZDc0MTBjZjRkOWU1YjMiLCJyZXF1ZXN0X3R5cGUiOiIxIn0.AFK3zGF5HvIEl2Qr0cNHmmS97zJmfolipuUKOGdJzUY"

**you can check the encode and decode values here:**

https://jwt.io/#debugger[image]

Comment: Note that in your question you mentioned you were _"trying to send my input parameters as **encrypted** format to server"_. However, the code provided in the answer, demonstrates [signing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2) the payload, not encrypting it. If you want to encrypt payload, have a look at [JWE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516).